# Адаптирование анимации в android

Tags: java, android, анимация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Я окончательно запутался.
Есть у меня условно кнопка, её размеры заданны в dp - тут все понятно, она отображается на всех устройства +/- одинаково.
Но как её одинаково перемещать на всех устройствах? Есть ли какой-то способ задать перемещение в dp? Или я что-то упустил?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
button10 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(pr10,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", 0, 250),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", 1050, 140));
        button10.setDuration(getSpeed());
        button10.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        button10.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
        button10.start();
```

---

up:

```
По экрану движутся кнопки (около 10 шт), пример анимации выше, при нажатии на любую из них создается новая кнопка, которая отправляется на свое расположение (зависит от очередности нажатия):

ObjectAnimator button_copy_button10 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(copy_pr10,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", ListCoordinateX_1.get(0)),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", LineY_1.get(0)));
        button_copy_button10.setDuration(1500);
        button_copy_button10.start();
```

Координаты ListCoordinateX_1.get(0) и  LineY_1.get(0)) берутся из списка. Вот эти  точки мне и надо задавать так, что бы они были одинаковы под все разрешения.

---

up:

Разобрался, сделал так:
        protected ArrayList LineY_1 = new ArrayList();

```
    public Point viewLocatedAt(View v) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    return new Point(x, y);
    } //определение координат

    int f = viewLocatedAt(imv5).y - (pr1.getHeight()/4 );
    LineY_1.clear();
    LineY_1.add(f);
```

- imv5 - элемент куда должна переместиться кнопка
- pr1 - кнопка. Так как все они одинаковы, то используются размеры первой.

Comment: вы лучше напишите постановку задачи

Comment: Дополнил в основном посту

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы "работало на всех экранах", то вам нужно узнавать размер экрана, устанавливать строгий размер в пикселях и двигать кнопки в пикселях. Я вам уже говорил, что в старом движке анимации есть удобный способ задать перемещение относительно родителя, вот там можно некоторые расчеты опустить в зависимости от постановки задачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно решить проблему в лоб - переводить нужное количество dp в пиксели в рантайме. px = dp * scale, где скейл можно получить из описания дисплея

```
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но  все равно не решило проблему. На разных дисплеях имеются различия. Как избежать этого?

Comment: @Freijer можно конкретнее? Какие дисплеи и какого плана отличия

Comment: прикрепил скрин. Конечная точка движения  отличается на разных устройствах

Comment: Все еще мало информации... нужно конкретные устройства назвать и насколько перемещаете, если цифра отличается от кода в вопросе. Думаю проблема в том, что если у устройств разные размеры экрана(следовательно и разные density) при одинаковом расширении, то размер экрана в dp тоже отличается. И если для одного fullHD экрана 700dp это "пол", то для другого это может быть где-то 80% от высоты

Comment: @Freijer https://material.io/resources/devices/ вот тут можно посмотреть. Например у Sony Xperia Z ultra и Nexus 5x расширение одинаковое, а density разные, в итоге высота в dp для  первого 960, для второго 731

Comment: Вышел из дома, позже добавлю значения перемещений. А как в таком случае сделать, что бы перемещение одинаково отображлось на разных устройствах?

Comment: @Freijer Зависит от эффекта, который вы хотите достичь. Высчитывать перемещение в рантайме или использовать, скажем, ConstraintLayout с разными ConstraintSet